# Add new columns in one table based on new entries in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: sessions and assignments. This assignments table has a column called `scriptname` with strings as values. The sessions table has column names equal to `scriptname`+ the columns `id`, `uid`, `timein` and `timeout`. As I add new instances to assignments I get new values in the `scriptname` column which I want to add as new columns to sessions with default values of 0. How do I do this?

What I currently do is drop the table and create a new table based on the `scriptname` column. The problem is of course I lose all my data.

```
DROP TABLE sessions;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'CREATE TABLE sessions (',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
      CONCAT(scriptname, ' BOOL DEFAULT 0')
      SEPARATOR ','),
    ');')
FROM
  assignments
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

ALTER TABLE sessions
ADD COLUMN `timeout` timestamp not null FIRST,
ADD COLUMN `timein` timestamp not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FIRST,
ADD COLUMN `uid` VARCHAR(128) not null FIRST,
ADD COLUMN `id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY not null FIRST;
```

I hope somebody can help me out as I'm really not an expert on sql! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're regularly adding and removing columns from a table, your design is wrong. Dynamic information should be in column values, not column names.

Comment: Can u be somewhat more explanatory.can u give the values in scriptname and also the desired output session table

Answer (score 8):

Consider, instead, adding rows to a table.  Then, later, "pivot" to make columns *while displaying* the output.

Adding columns is quite clumsy, as you are finding.  Adding too many columns will eventually hit some limit.  Adding rows is essentially unlimited.

Pivoting is discussed many times in this forum, so I won't repeat those discussions here.

Answer (score 3):

You must know the list of the newly added columns somehow. E.g you may have a column called `date_added` where you have recorded when the new session was added.

If you do not have such column then you can get the list of columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Then all you need is to create an `ALTER TABLE` script like this (this will add new columns to the table for the sessions added in April):

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE sessions ',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
      CONCAT('ADD COLUMN ', scriptname, ' BOOL DEFAULT 0')
      SEPARATOR ','),
    ';')
FROM
  assignments
WHERE scriptname NOT IN (
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'sessions'
  AND table_schema = '<your schema>')
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

-- this should generate this:
-- ALTER TABLE sessions 
--  ADD COLUMN blah1 BOOL DEFAULT 0, 
--  ADD COLUMN blah2 BOOL DEFAULT 0;
```

However, I must comment that you need to re-design how you store your data. The way you store it is not the optimal. You need to store the sessions in rows, not in column like you do. If you need to present the data this way you can build a query to pivot the data.

Comment: I don't have such a column. The newly added columns = scriptnames column from assignments minus the column names in sessions.

Comment: So currently the sessions are stored in rows, however I want to describe more features on the sessions which requires the addition of new columns.

Comment: There you go: you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to find a list of already added column, as per my updated answer

Comment: Ok I'll try your solution, I'll get back to you on the results.

Comment: Something not right yet:
#1054 - Unknown column 'sessions' in 'where clause'

Comment: `'sessions'` needs to be in the single quotes `'` not in the accent symbols (`)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: Thanks for that. Found a typo and fixed it. Try again

Comment: Thanks cha. You get your well-deserved points. It worked. You saved me a big hassle.

Comment: Final Question: On my local server the script works fine. On my remote server the script throws the following error:
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'timeout'. 
Timeout is one of the columns in sessions but not in assignments. However it should not make this error. Could this be a version thing between remote and local server? The database is exactly the same with the same names.

Comment: Or I get this:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT 0,ADD COLUMN inhoudbalk2 BOOL DEFAULT 0,ADD COLUMN inhoudcilinder1 BOOL ' at line 1

Comment: I think your @sql variable is not big enough to hold all the sql statement. Make its size bigger, ie varchar(2000)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that's the issue as the size would be smaller than on my local server. The #1064 might have been due to a bad row in assignments. Now I constantly get this: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'timeout'. It is very strange and I don't know what to do about it. 'timeout' is of course my timestamp which is not a BOOL. But I don't understand why it's evaluating that column as it is not present in assignments.

Comment: Ok I've solved the issue. Timeout couldn't default to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 on the remote server. I've changed it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Weak data model here.
It's not for RDBMS - there, you're going to enforce the restrictions over your dataset through relations.

E.g., in your case, through making the `scriptname` a foreign key in your `sessions` table. 
Thus, you'll be having multiple records in `sessions` table per what you consider one record of your type, each containing 1 scriptname value (which stands for column name in your model), and the associated value (the field value in your table). 
Then you can kind of "rotate" and assemble that two columns into a row on the client side.

Otherwise, if you're firm about keeping that denormilised non-rigid data structure at any price - you better opt out for some column oriented/multimodel DB, like Apache Cassandra. There you can alter your columnfamily/table structure right on the fly, no need to stop/drop/recreate/run again.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, dynamically generating an ever-growing list of columns is clearly not what you should be doing. SQL is just not designed for that.

Where it me, based on the limited information I have about how you're using this, I would have a third table (with two columns: "scriptname" and "value") which could be joined with the sessions table. That way you can have any number of assignment per session (which it sounds like is your objective).

Answer (score 2):

You can set a trigger on insertion of new entries in another table.Like --

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ADD_COLUMN_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_1`
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE table_2........;
 END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And how would that look like in my example?